# AWS, RDS: How to migrate +40GB Postgres database from AWS ec2 instance to RDS using hard disk files?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

It seems migrating Postgres database using data directory is viable:

[How To Move a PostgreSQL Data Directory to a New Location on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But in case of RDS because `SSH`ing to the RDS is not possible I am here to ask if there is any way to speed up my Postgres database migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.PostgreSQL.html):

> **AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS)** is a cloud service that makes it easy to migrate relational databases, data warehouses, NoSQL databases, and other types of data stores. You can use AWS DMS to migrate your data into the AWS Cloud, between on-premises instances (through an AWS Cloud setup), or between combinations of cloud and on-premises setups.